# apache marathon: my docker image keeps failing

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon, dockerhub

Im following steps on [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker-private-registry.html)

I've created a json file as such:

```
{
  "id": "/myjavabuild-2",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 1024,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "hub.docker.com/eugenepark3/myjavabuild",
      "network": "HOST",
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": false
    }
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10001,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
  "uris": [
    "file:///etc/docker.tar.gz"
  ],
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "file:///etc/docker.tar.gz",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    }
  ]
}
```

it keeps erroring out on Marathon.

Is this the correct way to pull docker image from hub.docker.com?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: it just says task_failed. how do you debug in marathon? @janisz

Comment: You can skip `hub.docker.com/`

Comment: @Tobi yeah that worked without hub.docker.com/